# Autosizing Textbox in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign

I was wondering if there was a way to autosize a drawn out textbox to fit the height of the text in PS. Something similar to inDesign where if you double-click the bottom-center draggable point of the textbox it adjusts accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a function specifically for that, but if you right click the text layer and convert the paragraph text to point text then back again it will get the job done.

Comment: Wish Adobe made a one-click feature that would solve this but this method solves the issue nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlEdwards You could make it into an action